# how to identify grouped column and hidden column separately?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-2010, excel-interop, vba

I have one excel containing few grouped columns. Inside that group few columns are HIDDEN.( right click hide). When the group is collapsed .Hidden property of all the columns returns true, which I don't want. Is there is way to identify originally Hidden columns apart from other group columns in a collapsed group ?

Comment: why don't you expand the group, count the hidden columns, then collapse the group back?

Comment: Using the group is a way to change the Hidden property, so both alter the same property. I fear there is no way to distiguish between the methods used once they are used...

Comment: are you referring to an Excel Outline when you talk about these 'groups' ?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman : That what is found the best way to do it initially, but there can be N number of expanded and collpased groupes, so if I expand few collapsed groups then how do I remeber those groupes in order to preserve the original state after I complete my work ?

Comment: @whytheq : Yes , if the there groupes then I guess Outline property is a way to identify that , I tried using that along with Hidden property but doesnt not look usefull. Because when the goupe is collapsed then outline property and hidden property will return true for all the columns and there wont be any way to distinguise between the collapsed and hidden columns/rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't fully understand the question but in VBA I can test to see if a column is hidden like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestFunction()

  'hide a few columns and then run me<<<<<<<<<<
  Dim mySearchColumn As Integer
  mySearchColumn = (CInt(Application.InputBox("input a column number")))

  MsgBox ("you wanted to know about column " & mySearchColumn & ". Is it hidden: " & IsColumnHidden(mySearchColumn))

End Sub

Function IsColumnHidden(targetColumn As Integer) As Boolean
    IsColumnHidden = False
    If Columns(targetColumn).EntireColumn.Hidden Then
        IsColumnHidden = True
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Columns(targetColumn).EntireColumn.Hidden will return true in TWO cases 1) When the the column is actually hidden 2) When this column is part of a group which is collapsed.

Comment: (I'll try to set up a model to see if we can distinguish)